# how to remove extra padding or margin inside an absolute block?

Tags: html, css

I would to recreate something like this illustration 
[image: illustration]

And I cant fix a padding (or margin issue). Here is what I tried : http://jsfiddle.net/kl94/RZPRS/2/

```
.circles {
    background-color: red;

    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.circle-title {
    background-color: orange;

    position:relative;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;

    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
/*     -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px; */

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.circle-reads {
    background-color: #28dd21;

    position:relative;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;

    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
/*     -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px; */

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

The constraint is the red div which must be absolute to constraint to top/right parent div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that being the case, you might as well position the other two elements `absolute` as well. You'll need to give the red div a fixed height and width since it is positioned `absolute`

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZPRS/5/).

```
.circles {
    background-color: red;
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.circle-title {
    background-color: orange;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px; 
}

.circle-reads {
    background-color: #28dd21;
    position:absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

If you want the two circles to not have a height width specified you can try this. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZPRS/10/). I feel like it will need as much 'babysitting' as setting height and width though.

Comment: It works just like a charm, BUT I don't like to set a size "manually" of the .circles (red) div. That's why I wanted a relative position.

Comment: The problem with not setting a height width is going to be losing the effect of a circle as your content grows

Comment: I added another option in my answer

Comment: oh no, you misunderstand what I mean, I was talking about the red div (.circles), I don't want to set a width/height on it. I would like it fits its child (just like a span).

Comment: Yeah that is going to be tough because when you float it right or position it absolute, it isn't a block level element.

Comment: See my new JSFiddle below. If you add a margin-right to your TITLE circle, you do not need a width or height on the red div.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a class to your `p` tags and also set their margin and padding to 0.

```
<p class="p">TITLE</p>
<p class="p">65 reads</p>
```

CSS

```
.p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You may also want to add `float: right;` to your lower div.

```
.circle-reads {
    float: right;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZPRS/6/)

EDIT: I did some more toying around and got it looking almost exactly how you want it.

[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZPRS/11/)

I don't have a specific link for these, it's just stuff I've learned over time and lots of Google searches while working with HTML/CSS.

Comment: Thanks for that tips, I didn't know the <p> "auto margin/padding", have you a link to share about those kind of tips ?